# Is there any way to choose the locators as per our choice through Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

As SIDE locate the element by its inbuilt logic.

Is there any way that we can get the locators as per choice.For example if I need only XPath of any element,or need CSS locator of any element. IS there any control available in IDE or any plug-in present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already checked the Target dropdown. You can see corresponding CSS,XPATH,Selenium locator values for the element. Yes, by default IDE uses Selenium, CSS, XPATH (in that order) to locate the element. But you can always change it by selecting the values from the drop down. [image]